# Windows 8 built-in maps app doesn't load anything

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, bing-maps

It doesn't load any map tiles:

[image]

I'm using Windows 8 Pro x64.

How to fix?

Comment: How are you connected? Has it ever worked and just stopped or never? Do other apps work?

Comment: The PC is connected with 802.11N to the ASUS RT-N56U home router, which is connected with 100 mbit/sec Ethernet to the Scientific Atlanta WebSTAR EPC2100R2 DOCSIS cable modem. Today I've tried to use this application for the first time. Apps running on the classic desktop work great, "modern UI" apps e.g. weather can't access the Internet.

Comment: Could be blocked by firewall or AV see this http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/windows-8-pro-x64-apps-wont-connect-to-internet/b4813031-2a20-4a0e-9932-d0b8566da379

Comment: I've got no 3-rt party security products.

Comment: So it's not just maps, *no* Metro app can access the net? Even Metro IE?

Comment: That's correct. When the IE is a default browser (I use Opera BTW), and set to work in Metro desktop, it says "This page can't be displayed •Make sure the web address http://google.com is correct."